# plink won't return to command prompt

Tags: bash, plink

I try to execute a bash script via plink. Script looks something like this:

```
echo "@ Starting process..."
./bin/process "process.cfg" &
disown %1
echo "@ Done!"
```

When i execute this script in a terminal on linux, everything works fine. After the "Done!" line I get a command prompt (as expected).

Now when I run this script via plink, the output stops afyer the "Done!" line, but plink won't return to the command prompt and "hangs" until +c.

The script is placed in a file and given to plink with the -m parameter

I tried addind 'logout', 'exit', 'set -e' at the end of the script, but it doesn't help. Also adding -batch, -T or -N to the plink command brought no success.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, it seems I had to detach stdout/err from the terminal.
In a normal terminal this wouldn't matter ofcourse, but plink remained in a "busy" state because of this.

So, inside my bash script (which executed the command) I had to change:

./bin/process "process.cfg" &

to:

./bin/process "process.cfg" /dev/null 2>&1 &

plink now returns the correct "finished" state at the end of the bash script.

Comment: Thanks - I was battling with similar issue trying to start Linux hosted WebLogic from a Windows hosted script. Redirecting output of startWebLogic.sh to /dev/null seems to have fixed it. (upvote)

Comment: Is this missing a '>' before the /dev/null?

Comment: Hey guys, How to do plink disconnect / logout when my remote script completes? "plink.exe -ssh domain -pw password /home/myscript.sh > output-deploy.txt"

Answer (score 5):

`plink.exe -P PORT_NUM -v USERNAME@HOST_IP -pw PASSWD "COMMAND >/dev/null &"`

- `&` would move your process to the background
- `> /dev/null` allows your command run silently by getting stdout/stderr to output to a dummy null device

note: the shell command is wrapped in "double quotations"

Answer (score 0):

Plink has a `-batch` parameter which disable all interactive prompts. It may be what you need here to avoid hanging until ctrl-C.

Comment: Forgot to mention I already tried -batch, -T, -N...  didn't help.